# C# Repeating method runs only once

Tags: c#, function, repeat

I am making little and simple code, problem is that my code don't want to run more than once, it runs once and then the whole program close.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace C_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            while(true){
            Random random = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Generating ladder...");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.Clear();
            int number = random.Next(0,15);
            CreateLadder(number);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nTo repeat, press 'r'");
            char name = (char)Console.Read();
            if(name != 'r'){
                break;
            }
            }
        }

        public static void CreateLadder(int num){
            //Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try debugging to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The line…

```
char name = (char)Console.Read();
```

Is not doing what you think it is doing. Specifically, from the MSDN documentation. In the “Remarks” section….

> Subsequent calls to the Read method retrieve your input one character
> at a time. After the final character is retrieved, Read blocks its
> return again and the cycle repeats.

If you type “r” then the loop will execute two (2) times then exit. The first time through it sees the “r” which will obviously fail on the line…

```
if (name != 'r')
```

and continue. When it gets to the line…

```
char name = (char)Console.Read();
```

the second time… you will notice it “skips” the read and does not block and wait for the user to enter a letter. Instead it simply reads the next character in `name` which will be the return/newline. Then when it gets to the `if(name != ‘r’`)` it will succeed and exit. If you type 'rrr' the loop will iterate through the code 4 times etc...

One solution is to use the `Console.ReadKey()` instead. Something like….

```
ConsoleKeyInfo name = Console.ReadKey();
if (name.KeyChar != 'r') {
   break;
}
```

I hope that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `Random` line to BEFORE the `while` loop.

Instead of `Read()`, I'd use `ReadKey()` like this:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
if (key.KeyChar != 'r')
```